How to deal with a third party DLL exporting STL symbols?
I am working on a project that is dependent on a third-party DLL. For reasons unknown, this DLL exports (most but not all) of the symbols for std::vector<unsigned char>:
$ dumpbin.exe -exports Problem.lib | grep 'std::vector'
                  ??0?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@$$QEAV01@@Z (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > &&))
                  ??0?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@$$QEAV01@AEBV?$allocator@E@1@@Z (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > &&,class std::allocator<unsigned char> const &))
                  ??0?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > const &))
                  ??0?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@AEBV?$allocator@E@1@@Z (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > const &,class std::allocator<unsigned char> const &))
                  ??0?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@AEBV?$allocator@E@1@@Z (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(class std::allocator<unsigned char> const &))
                  ??0?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@V?$initializer_list@E@1@AEBV?$allocator@E@1@@Z (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(class std::initializer_list<unsigned char>,class std::allocator<unsigned char> const &))
                  ??0?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@XZ (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(void))
                  ??0?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@_KAEBEAEBV?$allocator@E@1@@Z (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(unsigned __int64,unsigned char const &,class std::allocator<unsigned char> const &))
                  ??0?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@_KAEBV?$allocator@E@1@@Z (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(unsigned __int64,class std::allocator<unsigned char> const &))
                  ??1?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@XZ (public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::~vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(void))
                  ...

This means that if we attempt to use std::vector<unsigned char> anywhere else in the codebase, the application will fail to link due to duplicate symbols:
Problem.lib(Problem.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >::~vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >(void)" (??1?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in Application.obj
   Creating library C:\Users\Parker\project\Application.lib and object C:\Users\Parker\Project\Application.exp
C:\Users\Parker\project\Application.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

I do not have the source code for this DLL and am unable to obtain a new version of it from the vendor. I have no reason to believe that these symbols were exported intentionally, but there is no chance of seeing this mistake fixed on the vendor's end.
I have thought of a few potential workarounds for this issue:

Modify the stub .lib to remove these symbols from the list of exported symbols. I have no idea if this can be done and have been unable to find the right search terms to figure that out.
Use C++11's extern template feature to try to just use the implementations in the DLL. This feels weird, as I've never seen extern template used across a DLL boundary, and I don't know if it is even supposed to work. My experiments thus far have been unsuccessful.
Just avoid using std::vector<unsigned char> entirely in application code. This feels extreme, but may actually require the least effort in the short term.

I realize this is an incredibly niche and stupid situation, but any guidance on potential workarounds would very much be appreciated.

I would probably just wrap the offending .lib into its own DLL that exports only what I need and none of the STL symbols, and then have the main app use that DLL instead.

I haven't done anything like this in ages, but wasn't there once an IMPLIB tool that let you create your own lib file for any dll?

@500-InternalServerError you are probably thinking of Borland/Embarcadero's implib.exe tool. Such .lib files would only work for C++Builder, but the question is tagged Visual C++.

@RemyLebeau: Yes, you are correct.

If library has an exported function which is part of their API and which is supposed to return a std::vector(or take one as input), they might have exported those symbols to eliminate warnings generated by visual studio. I know this doesn't help you fix it but could explain how it happened in the first place.

I'm not sure if it can strip symbols from a .lib file, but Microsoft's LIB.EXE can be used to create clean stub .lib files for existing DLLs.
